# How to add ontap function to my bottom nav bar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I want to add on tap function to my bottom nav bar items, My code looks like this:

```
BottomNavigationBarItem(
  icon: Icon(
    Icons.settings,
    color: Colors.grey,
  )
)
```

Comment: I would recommend you to read the BottomNavigationBar documentation

Answer (score 1):

There is an onTap function of BottomNavigationBar , example code

```
 bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.call),
            label: 'Calls',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.camera),
            label: 'Camera',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.chat),
            label: 'Chats',
          ),
        ],
        onTap: (i) {
         

        },
```

Comment: How do I set the ontap for each icons boss

Comment: from @Madhav Anadkat answer ,onTap:(i){} the "i" is the index of the items. use can use that index to manipulate how u want the action should be.

Comment: Bro I would appreciate if you could point out the code.im totally lost

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75958342/8929068) the `onTap` function is used to interact with the `bottomNavbar` items. The `i` in it is for index.

```
onTap: (i) {
             if(i == 0){
               print("tapped on calls"); 
             }
             if(i == 1){
               print("tapped on camera"); 
             }
             if(i == 2){
               print("tapped on chats"); 
             }
            },
```

Now in the conditions just add what you want to do when clicked on `bNavBar` items.